# flink table count rows with the same entry

Tags: count, apache-flink

I have a table with different entries in the columns (but I don't know all of them)

```
table:    
column1 | column2
   x1   |    y1
   x1   |    y2
   x2   |    y2
   x3   |    y1
   x3   |    y2
```

Now I want get a list or dictionary where all entries of the first column are count:

```
dict = (x1:2, x2:1, x3:2)
```

I tried:

```
table = env.readCsvFile(tablepath).as('column1, 'column2)
var content = table.select('column1)
content.count()
```

And I tried to use the Word-Count example [link](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-scala-examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/examples/scala/wordcount/WordCount.scala), but it need an array of strings as input?! so

```
Wordcount(content) or Wordcount(content.toString())
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the count for each value in `column1` you need to group by `column1` and count:

```
table = env.readCsvFile(tablepath).as('column1, 'column2)
var content = table.groupBy('column1').select('column1.count)
```

The input to `WordCount` specifies the input and output file or you data (it expects two Strings---or none, in to used in-memory example data and print the result to `stdout`). The parameters, are not the data to be processed though.

Comment: i tried it and got this error message:
Dangling GroupBy operation. Did you forget a SELECT statement

Comment: I did not recognize that you are using TableAPI... I just updated my answer.

Comment: i forgot to mention that.
thanks for the answer, it's working now

Comment: The next problem I get is the following:' I try to reduce to my table and just want to have specific rows. With the example and code above i get for the var content a table (2,2,1). Now I want to reduce my original table, s.t. I have just the rows where content is < 2, i.e. 

`column1 | column2
    x2                y2`
. I tried: 
`var reducedtable = table.select('column1, 'column2).where(content < 2) `

Comment: Did you have a look into the Documentation? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/libs/table.html It should be "filter(...)" and not "where(...)".

Comment: I tried different things, but don't got the reduced table.

`var reducedtable = table.groupBy("column1").select("column1.count as count, column1").filter("count < 2")`

but the result is now 

`1 x2` and not `x2 y2`

Comment: I guess this should not work at all... If you apply an aggregation (-> count), you cannot simply "select" the second column, too. You need to omit it, or apply an aggregation to the second column, too. (Basically, the rule is, aggregate all or none). Thus, try `var reducedtable = table.groupBy("column1").select("column1.count as count").filter("count < 2")`

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY` and aggregation in SQL? This is the same principle. You can only have columns in your "SELECT columns" clause that are either in the "GROUP BY" clause of if you apply an aggregation function to the column.